# How do I say "the school was sold to that big company"?

Tags: grammar, usage

My question is related to the position of 给.

Do I say:

> 学校被卖给那个公司了。

or

> 学校给那个公司被卖了。

Thanks!

Comment: Sold to = 被卖给, so the 1st one. To complete, add a 了 to indicate the completion, like 被卖给了. The 2nd one seems a little bit problematic, since there are two words to indicate passive actions, which is not usually accepted when used in the same sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position of 给 in the first sentence you have is correct, you would just add 了 to indicate the completion of the act to make it flow better

> 那所学校被卖给那个大公司了

Comment: Thanks, I knew there should be a 了 in there. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

Some alternatives :

> 1. 学校被卖给了那个公司。
> 2. 学校被那个公司收购了/买走了。
> 3. 学校被那个公司给收购了。